# Incorrect syntax near '.'. for dynamic pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am pivoting a table based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/10404455/1349141

This code works perfect. However, when I modify the code for my tables. It shows a mysterious Incorrect syntax near '.' for the row below the second `declare`.

Here is my code

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
--Incorrect syntax near '.' 
SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(Crop) + ',' FROM (select distinct [Crop] from [FAF40].[dbo].[county_farm_acres2014] ) as tmp

set @query = 
'SELECT * from 
(
    select StateCode, CountyCode, Crop from [FAF40].[dbo].[county_farm_acres2014]
) src
pivot 
(
    max(PlantedAcres) for Crop in (' + @cols + ')
) piv'

execute(@query)
go
```

Comment: why # next to from? in ur code... Select StateCode, CountyCode, Crop from # [FAF40].[

Comment: Edited. It's a typo

Comment: Did you debugged by printing your @query? does @cols have more data appended in subquery?

Comment: Thanks. Printed and working on checking the query.

Comment: Possibly an extra ',' at end of @cols

Comment: @KeithL You are right. Problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: I've always seen people use stuff to remove it

Comment: You also, on line 9, missed the aggregated column PlantedAcres from the select that produces the data (i.e. SELECT PlantedAcres , StateCode, CountyCode, Crop FROM ... )